# Android Fragment container argument in onCreateView

Tags: android, fragment, android-inflate, viewgroup

I wonder where container argument in onCreateView() method of Flagment come from , is that a ViewGroup of the activity which has this fragment or something else ? I wonder it cause i don't know what ViewGroup that xml of fragment attract to in this code .thanks for your time

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list,container,true);



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container parameter passed to onCreateView() is the parent ViewGroup (from the activity's layout) in which your fragment layout will be inserted.
Rest you can refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this question was down voted. IMO it's a good question trying to understand what the framework is giving us from its callbacks.

I have the same question, and after reading some official docs, here is my theory:

To make it more specific, I think the container is the FragmentContainerView in this [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic). Basically it's the resource id which you add your fragment to. For example, if we do

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container_view, fragment).commitNow();
```

Then the container is the ViewGroup identified by R.id.container_view.